# svg path gets scribling ,when drawing on line at mozila firefox

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Is there is anyway stop the scribling

normal(chrome) image:

[image]

scribled image(firefox):

[image]

I am using code to generate drawing path

```
document.createElementNS(NS, "path");
```

Here is the JsFiddle : [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shankarrjg/j01s9v2a/3/)

Comment: Your code should be in the question. It's clearly not just what you've posted inline and is presumably all in the jsfiddle.

Comment: I think, you must draw a path on the line slowly, Iam using firefox 52.0.1 version, windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be a difference between how `offsetX` and `offsetY` are implemented between Chrome and Firefox.

In Firefox, when you cross the red line, the `offsetX` and `offsetY` values being returned are relative to the top-left of the *red line*, not the SVG. Which is why your line values are jumping to the top of the screen and left a bit.

I am not sure whether this is a bug in Firefox or not.

In any case, you should not really be using `offsetX` and `offsetY` for this purpose.  The "correct" approach is normally to get the `clientX` and `clientY` coords and translate them to SVG coordinates.

```
function screenToSVG(clientX, clientY)
{
  // Create an SVGPoint for future math
  var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = clientX;
  pt.y = clientY;

  // Apply the inverse of the CTM (SVG Current Transform Matrix) to get
  // the equivalent point in SVG coordinate space
  return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works even if the SVG is not drawn at 1:1 scale.  For example if it has a `viewBox`.

```js
(function() {
    var stage = jQuery('#stage');
    var isMouseDown = false;
    var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var penCount = 0;
    stage.on('mousedown', mouseDown);
    stage.on('mousemove', mouseMove);
    stage.on('mouseup', mouseUp);
    $('#stageClear').on('click',()=>{
    $('.shape').remove()
    })

    function mouseDown(event) {
        var pt = screenToSVG(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        isMouseDown = true;
        var shape = document.createElementNS(NS, "path");
        shape.setAttribute("class", "shape");
        shape.setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
        shape.setAttribute("id", "pen" + penCount);
        shape.setAttribute("stroke", "#2795ee");
        shape.setAttribute("stroke-width", "4px");
        shape.setAttribute("strokeLinecap", "round");
        shape.setAttribute("d", "M " + pt.x + " " + pt.y + " ");
        shape.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");
        stage.append(shape);
        ++penCount;
    }

    function mouseMove(event) {
        var pt = screenToSVG(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        if (isMouseDown) {
            var depth = jQuery('#pen' + (penCount - 1)).attr("d");
            jQuery('#pen' + (penCount - 1)).attr("d", depth + "L " + pt.x + " " + pt.y + " ");
        }
    }

    function mouseUp(event) {
        isMouseDown = false;
    }
    
    function screenToSVG(clientX, clientY)
    {
        // Create an SVGPoint for future math
        var svg = stage[0];
        var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
        pt.x = clientX;
        pt.y = clientY;
    
        // Apply the inverse of the CTM (SVG Current Transform Matrix) to get
        // the equivalent point in SVG coordinate space
        return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    }

})();
```

```css
#stage{
  width:100%;
  height:610px;
  border:1px solid;
}
#stageClear{
 cursor:pointer;
}
#stagetext{
  user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="stage" >
<text id="stagetext" x="10" y="10px">draw on the stage using mouse</text>
  <line x1="50" y1="300" x2="800" y2="300" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
<button id="stageClear"> clear</button>
```